# Dynamic Loading: Undefined Symbol In Shared Static Library

Tags: dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading

I have an executable that loads `.so` plugins.

The executable is linked with `-rdynamic` so that symbol callback can occur.

I have a static library that is included in the executable.  This has a function called `BLAH_hello()` in the `.a`

The static library **is not used** in the executable.  ie there are no calls to `BLAH_hello()` in the executable code.

However, the `.so` does have calls to `BLAH_hello()`.

When I `dlopen()` the `.so` it complains about an undefined symbol to `BLAH_hello()`

**If** I include a dummy call to `BLAH_hello()` in the executable code, like `BLAH_hello(NULL);`.  The symbol is included in the executable and when the `.so` is loaded it finds the symbol.

I'm sure I could also link the `.so` against the `.a` but multiple dynamically loaded `.so`'s use the `BLAH_hello` call so it makes sense to have it in the executable.  I'm also worried about symbol conflict if I link the library into each `.so`.

So what I'm wondering, is how to get the symbols of the `.a` into the executable even if they aren't actually *used* in the executable?

Comment: Linking the .so against the .a is the obvious and correct thing to do.

Comment: Thanks Neil.  I have three `.so` plugins that will need to be linked against that `.a` I won't have symbol conflicts when i load all the `.so`'s into my executable?

Comment: No, you won't, otherwise you would not be able to use operating system and other standard functions in .sos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nbt:

> Linking the `.so` against the `.a` is the obvious and correct thing to
>   do.

This should not generate symbol conflicts when loading the `.so` into an executable.

Answer (score 4):

> When I dlopen() the .so it complains about an undefined symbol to BLAH_hello()
>
> If I include a dummy call to BLAH_hello() in the executable code, like BLAH_hello(NULL);. The symbol is included in the executable and when the .so is loaded it finds the symbol.

That is completely normal and expected. It's just [how linkers work with archive libraries](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).

If you must include `BLAH_hello` into the main executable, add `-Wl,-u,BLAH_hello` to the executable link line.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same from source code? (e.g.: `__attribute__((something))`)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the linker discards .o files with no referenced symbols. This is problem, when the executable needs to dlopen() external shared libs. In such case the linker options '--whole-archive' and '--no-whole-archive' can be used, when linking the executable. All .a libs between these options will have all symbols included. It increases the executable size, but removes the need to link to executable's static libs.